# How to play videos on CarPlay?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, carplay

I have a web link to a video, in iOS I can open it with AVFoundation/AVKit frameworks inside AVPlayerViewController/AVPlayer.

But how can I open it in CarPlay?

Text from CarPlay documentation:

> You cannot play video media items directly using the Media Player
>   framework. To play back videos containing MPMediaItem objects, use an
>   AVPlayer object from AVFoundation. The system player also provides a
>   way to play video items using the system apps.

```
extension AppDelegate: CPListTemplateDelegate {
    func listTemplate(_ listTemplate: CPListTemplate, didSelect item: CPListItem, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if let url = item.userInfo as? String {
            self.playVideo(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this

Comment: @AJSanjay no, sorry :(

Comment: Hi I found a solution to play video on carplay. But to test it on device I need a apple certificate enrolled in apple developer program

Answer (score 2):

I will share the steps to follow to play a sample video on carplay

in Appdeligate.h Add the following header file

```
import CarPlay
import AVKit
```

Then add `CPApplicationDelegate`

Add these deligate methords

```
 // MARK: - CPApplicationDelegate methods
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didConnectCarInterfaceController interfaceController: CPInterfaceController, to window: CPWindow) {
    print("[CARPLAY] CONNECTED TO CARPLAY!")

    // Keep references to the CPInterfaceController (handles your templates) and the CPMapContentWindow (to draw/load your own ViewController's with a navigation map onto)
    self.interfaceController = interfaceController
    self.carWindow = window
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4") else
                        {
                            return
                        }
                        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
                        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
                        playerController.player = player
                        player.play()

            window.rootViewController = playerController
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDisconnectCarInterfaceController interfaceController: CPInterfaceController, from window: CPWindow) {
    print("[CARPLAY] DISCONNECTED FROM CARPLAY!")
}
```

Also proceed the steps to add carplay entitlements

Comment: Is there a way to test without enrolling in apple developer program

Comment: No not possible

Comment: @F.Sviatoslav but this app will not be accepted by apple review team.

Comment: @AJSanjay yep, I get it, it's just for internal use, thanks anyway :)

Comment: You are Welcome

Comment: @F.Sviatoslav Did this end up working? You didn't mark it as an answer. Were you able to use AVPlayer in the CarPlay app?